Google play scrapper : Continuation_Token
review_list = []
reviews_total = 10000
continuation_token = None
while len(review_list)<reviews_total:
    result, continuation_token = reviews(
      'com.this.is.app.id.google',
      lang='id',
      country='id',
      sort=Sort.MOST_RELEVANT,
      count=200,
      filter_score_with=None,
      continuation_token = continuation_token
    )
    review_list.extend(result)
    print("Total Result: ", len(review_list))

The program code was running smoothly a few weeks ago. However, when I tried to run it again, it entered an endless loop, printing "Total Result:199" instead of the expected 200,400,600,and so on. I suspect the issue may be related to the continuation_token, as the lack of a new continuation_token causes the scraping to repeat endlessly. When I tried to display the contents of the continuation_token, it showed the following:
<google_play_scraper.features.reviews._ContinuationToken at 0x7b7905835a20>
i don't know what it mean.
What I Tried: I attempted to scrape reviews from an application available on the Google Play Store.
Expected Outcome: I expected the code to run smoothly without errors and to retrieve 10,000 reviews.
Actual Outcome: However, the code entered an endless loop.
